# Two select statements both requiring $GET

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to have two select statements in one php file using the same `$GET['id']`.

The first select statement which is working is to populate a number of text fields based on which article i selected.

The second select statement i want to select comments from the comments table only for the article ID i got from the `$GET['id']`. This will have two populated forms one displaying the article information and the second displaying comments only for that article.

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$articleID = $_GET['id'];
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM article WHERE articleID = "' . $articleID . '"');
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
}
}
$articleID = $_GET['id'];
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE artID = "' . $articleID . '"');
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
}
?>
```

I've currently got a error that says unexpected }.

I'm not sure how i'm suppose to separate the two.

Comment: '$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
}' why  fetch statement starting with ) and ending with }

Comment: looks like you could use a join here

Comment: check this line in your code $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: I see four of } and only one {

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using prepared statements and supply any user data as separate arguments because you have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of `}` this in your code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']))
  {
   $articleID = $_GET['id'];
   $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM article WHERE articleID = "' .    $articleID . '"');
   $result1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $stmt2 = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE artID = "' . $articleID . '"');
   $result2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
 ?>
```

use $result1 for first select and $result2 for second

Comment: Stupid mistake of mine, It doesn't show any records for my article which is kinda frustrating.